# Please help in configuring Sendgrid and HostGator mx records

Tags: smtp, sendgrid, spam-marked

I am trying to send emails through Sendgrid SMTP and unfortunately, all emails were landing to spam. Upon checking from mail-tester.com service, I got to know an error message that "You are not allowed to use one of your sender email addresses" with a minus 3 score which I believe is causing the emails to land in the spam folder.

Here's the report URL: https://www.mail-tester.com/web-7n29r&reloaded=2

Sendgrid support is worthless in this case and continuously pestering me to upgrade to a dedicated IP and pro account, while I have no understanding of their platform to make the upgrade.

I did white label all the sending domains and link tracking.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is correct and by opening the explanation you whould have avoided asking this question.

> [Sender ID] `gunsafeslab.com` does not allow your server `167.89.106.6` to use `naser@gunsafeslab.com`
>
> Sender ID is like SPF, but it checks the FROM address, not the bounce address.
>
> What we retained as your current SPF record is:
>
> `v=spf1 a mx include:websitewelcome.com include:sendgrid.net ~all`
>
> More information about this error:
>
> `gunsafeslab.com ... _spf.google.com`: Maximum DNS-interactive terms
>   limit (`10`) exceeded

In order to send mail from Sendgrid your SPF record should have `include:sendgrid.net`.

Now it has `include:websitewelcome.com` having `include:spf.websitewelcome.com include:spf1.websitewelcome.com include:_spf.google.com` having more includes inside them. This will cause more than 10 DNS queries and the SPF checker will stop. Whether the `167.89.106.6` eventually exists in one of these includes doesn't matter, because it won't get there.

One way to sanitize these superfluous queries would be querying `TXT` records of what have been included; try to avoid includes that are only doing more includes. Here's a little chart showing all the DNS queries caused by `"v=spf1 a mx include:websitewelcome.com include:sendgrid.net ~all"`:

[image: a mx include:websitewelcome.com include:sendgrid.net]

All these causes a new DNS query:

- Red label shows every `include:` only containing more `include:` methods.
- Orange label shows `include:` methods also having actual `ip4`/`ip6` methods (green).
- Yellow label are other methods: `a` and `mx` needs to be queried separately, too.

Moreover, this has nothing to do with `MX` records as they are for *receiving* mail, not for sending. Also, your `A` and `MX` are eventually the same server, and could be replaced with single `ip4:192.254.236.206`.

If you only send mail from this one server and Sendgrid, your minimal SPF record would be:

```
"v=spf1 ip4:192.254.236.206 include:sendgrid.net ~all"`
```

That would cause only one extra DNS query. If you also send mail from Gmail, that'd be five with

```
"v=spf1 ip4:192.254.236.206 include:sendgrid.net include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

[image: ip4:192.254.236.206 include:sendgrid.net include:_spf.google.com]

Comment: Hi Esa,

I did open that explanation and I didn't understand a thing. I am not that technical.

Thanks a lot for helping me. Can you please guide me how do I include the sendgrid.com in my SPF domain as well, please?

Should I just replace websitewelcome.com with sendgrid.com or add a new line with sendgrid.com?

Comment: I tried to explain this a little in my edit.

Comment: I added a separate txt record with my naked domain in the name and balue as 

v=spf1 a mx include:sendgrid.net ~all

Please let me know if this is correct

Comment: Only one SPF record per hostname is allowed ([RFC 4408, 3.1.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4408#section-3.1.2)). The [SPF Common mistakes](http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/Common_mistakes) page may help you in creating a suitable record.

Comment: Thanks Esa. How do we remove the multiple includes include:spf.websitewelcome.com include:spf1.websitewelcome.com include:_spf.google.com you were talking in your previous comment.

This is so confusing :( I sincerely apologize for the noob questions and really thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Hope my edit clarifies the situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67488/discussion-between-naser-mohd-baig-and-esa-jokinen).

Comment: Hi @EsaJokinen, could you please help me with another issue regarding my SPF record? Here are the details: https://serverfault.com/questions/891873/mail-tester-com-shows-wrong-server-ip-please-help-me-figure-out-what-am-i-doing